# Prove f is monotone given f'(x) is never 0 on an interval.

Tags: derivatives, monotone-functions

I'm working on the following as part of a larger proof and am struggling with this last piece of the puzzle.

Let $f$ be differentiable on an interval $A$. If $f'(x)$ is never $0$ on $A$, then prove either $f'(x)>0$ or $f'(x)<0$ for all $x$ in $A$.

I think if I can solve this bit then I can solve the next piece which is to say that $f$ is monotone on $A$ and then ultimately that $f$ is one to one on $A$.

Thank you!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)

Comment: Can't believe I didn't see that! Thank you.